# How to pass any pdf link and open it

Tags: javascript

What i am trying to do is pass any pdf link and just open it. 
This is what i came up so far but it returns a blank page.

```
<input type="link" id="link" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Open"
onClick="javascript: window.open( document.getElementById('link').value);" />
```

I am trying to pass the link below

https://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf

Comment: Your `#link` input has no value.

Comment: ` returns a page with 404 not found.` and which url?

Comment: So what is the url in the page?

Comment: my bad it returns 404 and this url http://fiddle.jshell.net/Gv5bq/341/show/[object%20HTMLInputElement] Please check http://jsfiddle.net/Gv5bq/341/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you havet to do like this

```
<input type="link" id="link" value ="https://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf"/>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Open"
onClick="javascript: window.open( document.getElementById('link').value);" />
```

if working have look to jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/pranayamr/g5je1n3a/

you can try like this ,havent tested in chrom as i dont have it on my machine but might work in chrome too

function openInNewTab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}

Comment: Thanks Pranay. I tried that but it opens a blank page in new tab

Comment: actually it opens the pdf with firefox but not with chrome

Comment: can i make it dynamic?  it should open any pdf link that will be passed

Comment: @mike - its dynamic right now, if you change value in put to another file than it will open that file ,...so currently its dynamic as you can change value in input and click on open

Comment: But then we will have to change value everytime for new url. Can we just pass the value as input?

Comment: @mike - you can do like this <input type="button" id="btn" value="Open"
onClick="javascript: window.open('https://gradcollege.okstate.edu/sites/default/files/PDF_linking.pdf');" />...if you done want to change value